# Branch.io link opens the installed app from twitter shared link only.It used to work with facebook and email,but no more

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io

I have deep link generated using branch.io shared to twitter, email and Facebook.But clicking on the links in respective social networks works only in twitter, which opens the installed application.Facebook and email are not opening my application installed.Please help.

Comment: We need more details. Can you provide an email link that doesn't work on Facebook and email? What email apps are you opening the link in?

Comment: @AlexBauer I have an ios application installed on my device which generates deep links.These deep links opens my application when shared to twitter, but not with Facebook and Email.It used to work, but not anymore.

Comment: Yes, I got all that from the original question :). We need a few _additional_ details

Comment: @AlexBauer Could you please specify the details that should I provide?

Comment: As mentioned, let's start with an example of the link that isn't working, and information on the email app you are using to test

Comment: @AlexBauer Shall I share the link here ?

Comment: That would be fine. Or you can also submit a ticket to the Branch [Integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new)

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a note here for any who may coming across this ticket while researching similar issues.

Branch links are intended to open their associated apps when the app is installed on a device - or to redirect the user to the app's page on the App or Play Store if the app is not installed. Unfortunately, there are certain applications that prevent Branch links from functioning as intended. Generally speaking, these tend to be apps employ captive webviews. Some apps, Slack for example, allow users to turn off captive webviews and use Chrome or Safari - which solves this issue. Other apps, like Facebook, do not have such a workaround.

Branch's current recommendation for partners using Branch links in Facebook posts is to leverage iOS Deepviews. When iOS Deepviews are enabled, clicking on a Branch link in the Facebook feed will open the Facebook webview with the Deepview. The CTA button in such Deepviews works properly as a Universal Link, opening the app or leading users to the App Store as appropriate. Link information from the original Branch link will be available to the app when opened in this fashion, and Branch attribution and analytics will also work properly. This is the most robust app linking experience that can currently be achieved from the Facebook feed. Although not ideal because of the introduction of an additional Deepview, every other option involves some type of tradeoff.

Branch Deepviews can be enabled at the app level (i.e. for all of the app's links), at the link level, or specifically for Facebook and/or Twitter. Note that enabling this last option (always showing Deepviews only when links are clicked from Facebook and/or Twitter) does require assistance from Branch - partners can reach out to them at: support@branch.io.

On iOS, problems with an app's Universal Linking configuration can also lead to issues like the one reported here and are extremely common. Branch has made a Universal Linking Validtor tool available to help identify and resolve issues with Universal Linking. This tool can be found here: https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-linking-validator/guide/. A troubleshooting guide is also available, here: https://support.branch.io/solution/articles/6000153326-ios-universal-links-troubleshooting-guide.

As a general recommendation, test Branch links and ensure they are working properly from a standard app (like Notes on iOS) before testing in social media posts.